# How to split one column into two separated by according to third column in knex.js?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I have a task that I have been cracking my head off.

So I have this table `transactions` and it has 2 columns `bonus` and `type` like :

```
bonus | type      
20       1
15      -1
```

What I want is to have a query with `bonus` column divided into two columns `bonus_spent` and `bonus_left` by `type`.

It should probably look like this one:

```
bonus_left | bonus_spent
    20            15
```

I know I can duplicate tables and join them with where clause but is there any way I can do this operation on single query?

Comment: Is there some other column that identifies who/what the bonus refers to?

Comment: yeah there is a field that say it belongs to user_id

Comment: I took the liberty of removing `mysql` and `psql` tags as my memory is you're targeting Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vanilla SQL you would use conditional aggregation. We use the `user_id` column which indicates who the bonus belongs to and I've used `SUM` for aggregation to allow for there being more than one of each type of bonus:

```
SELECT user_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type =  1 THEN bonus ELSE 0 END) AS bonus_left,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = -1 THEN bonus ELSE 0 END) AS bonus_spent
FROM transactions
GROUP BY user_id
```

Output:

```
user_id     bonus_left  bonus_spent
1           20          15
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pRqpgfDt1Fi2pWgQQV8c3Z/1)

Comment: Good asnwer I have not thought this way but it works only if I need a sum right ?

Comment: @MereyNurlan no, if there is only one value for each `user_id` you will just get that value. You need to use some form of aggregation function as you need to `GROUP BY` the `user_id` to get all the values into one row. If you know there will only be one bonus of each type per user, you can use `MAX` or `MIN`instead of `SUM` as they would be more efficient. In that case you would remove the `ELSE 0` from the `CASE` expressions as it is not required.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick) and you should mark that answer correct IMHO. For completeness and some Knex:

```
knex('users AS u')
  .join('transactions AS t', 'u.id', 't.user_id')
  .select('u.id', 'u.name')
  .sum(knex.raw('CASE WHEN t.type = 1 THEN t.bonus ELSE 0 END AS bonus_left'))
  .sum(knex.raw('CASE WHEN t.type = -1 THEN t.bonus ELSE 0 END AS bonus_spent'))
```

Note that, lacking your table schema, this is untested. It'll look roughly like this though. You could also just embed the two `SUM`s as `knex.raw` in the select list, but this is perhaps a little more organised.

Consider creating the `type` as a [Postgres enum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-enum.html). This would allow you to avoid having to remember what a 'magic number' is in your table, instead writing comparisons like:

```
CASE WHEN type = 'bonus_left'
```

It also stops you from accidentally entering some other integer, like `99`, because Postgres will type-check the insertion.

I have a nagging concern that having bonus 'left' vs 'spent' in the same table reflects a wider problem with the schema (for example, why isn't the total amount of bonus remaining the only value we need to track?) but perhaps that's just my paranoia!

Comment: This is the part I was unable to supply. Thanks for filling in the gap.